# React Console warning --- React.createFactory()

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, warnings, recompose

I am facing the below warning in the console whenever my react application renders and every time the code re-renders, Can anyone help me out how to sort out this warning it would be highly appreciable.

> **Warning:** React.createFactory() is deprecated and will be removed in a future major release. Consider using JSX or use
> React.createElement() directly instead.

Comment: Either you've written some code that's calling `createFactory` or some library you're using is calling `createFactory`. Does the warning contain a stack trace?

Comment: @NicholasTower Yes it does have a stack trace and it shows **react.development.js** file, a dependency called recompose is actually triggering this, is it fine if I delete that module alone and I checked only that modules use this createFactory.

Comment: Which file is using recompose? That file will need to be rewritten to not depend on recompose ([recompose stopped being maintained in 2018](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose#a-note-from-the-author-acdlite-oct-25-2018)).

Comment: @NicholasTower, I also searched the term createFactory() is been used only inside the recompose module that's it. I am new to this coding side, can you please explain me how to check whether the other files are dependent or not? i checked that link but its hard to understand, could you please tell me what needs to be done?

Comment: `can you please explain me how to check whether the other files are dependent or not?` Yes, please add the full stack trace to your question, and i should be able to point out which component is using recompose.

Comment: @NicholasTower I have added entire trace,
react.development.js:315 Warning: React.createFactory() is deprecated and will be removed in a future major release. Consider using JSX or use React.createElement() directly instead.
    printWarning @ react.development.js:315
    warn @ react.development.js:278
    createFactoryWithValidation @ react.development.js:1827
    (anonymous) @ shouldUpdate.js:18
    pure @ pure.js:22
    (anonymous) @ compose.js:13
    enhance @ nivo-voronoi.esm.js:82
    ./node_modules/@nivo/voronoi/dist/nivo-voronoi.esm.js @ nivo-voronoi.esm.js:170

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nivo currently uses recompose, and so if you're using Nivo, you will see this warning. They are [aware of this warning](https://github.com/plouc/nivo/issues/884) and are actively working to fix it, but are not yet done.

You can continue to use the code just fine, as long as you don't upgrade your version of `react`. `createFactory` still works in current versions of react, so you will not have any bugs. If you need to upgrade your version of react to a version that does not have `createFactory`, you will either need to wait for Nivo to update their code, or you will need to stop using Nivo.

Comment: what is the Nivo??

Comment: [Nivo](https://nivo.rocks/) is a library for rendering graphs and charts.